# How to pass CLI options to heroku pg:psql?

Tags: heroku, psql

- **Given** `heroku pg:psql` works, connects to database
- **And** `$SQL` is a valid SQL query
- **When** I run `heroku pg:psql -c $SQL`
- **Then** I expect to see the results of the query
- **And** I expect `heroku` to exit with a status code of `0`

Instead, the `-c` option is ignored, `$SQL` is **not** executed, and an interactive prompt is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug, sorry about that :-/

I've reported it.

It appears that `pg:extras` might be the culprit, and if you didn't have that, it may work.  See [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/issues/71)

Try

```
heroku plugins:uninstall heroku-pg-extras
```

There's a work around - pipe the command in:

```
<<< "select count(*) from features;" | heroku pg:psql -a appname -c -
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, both workarounds succeed.  Though, what's the `<<<`?  I used `echo` for the first half of my pipe.

Comment: Heh.  Those are called [Here Documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).  They allow you to use delimiters to specify what text to read and then send along as standard input.